# Firebase storage rules based on custom parameters

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

How can I grant read-write access based on custom parameters, for example, 
When a user is registered with my app, a document is created and the document id is used to create a folder in firebase storage(so that I can ensure the uniqueness if every folder in firebase storage) The rule I am setting is a read permission for everyone who is authenticated and the write access is only for the user who created it and the admin only. Here is the rule I presently have in firebase storage.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write:if  request.auth.uid == userId || userId == asdfasfasdf
    }
  }
}
```

Is this approach correct or correct me if I am doing it wrong. I have gone through the documentation and it is a bit hard for me to understand.

Comment: `userId == asdfasfasdf` does not make sense. To give access to admins, you would need something like `request.auth.uid == 'adminuid'`, where `adminuid` is the UID of your admin user.