# Firebase Security rules to restrict access on all paths but one?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

> **Question:**
>
> For the different top-level firestore collections below, how to restrict access to all but one of the paths?

We are building a data schema in Firestore to support a chat app for teachers across multiple schools.

The top-level firestore collections include:

- `/siteAdminUsers`
- `/schools`
- `/schools/{schoolId}/teachers`
- `/schools/{schoolId}/chats`

Below is the security rules setup we are trying now - where we check for:

1. valid user auth
2. expected value exists in userClaim variable `request.auth.token.chatFlatList`

However, the read listener for `/messages` is being blocked.

> **Error message:**
>
> FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions

---

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    match /schools/{schoolId}/chats/{discussionId}/messages {
      allow write: if false;
      allow read: if request.auth != null
                  && request.auth.token != null
                  && request.auth.token.chatFlatList.val().contains($discussionId);
    }
}
```

---

**Details**

We are using cloud functions for all data read/write, so for almost every case we can just block all client access.

The one exception is for the chat discussions, where we need to set a snapshot listener in the mobile client to know when there are new messages.

**Sub-collection notes:**

At a school, there are discussion sessions for school staff (teachers, admins, etc)

```
/schools/{schoolId}/chats/{discussionId}
```

Where each *discussion-document* contains:

1. list of participant teacher ids
2. subcollection for actual messages where each document is an indivual posted message:

`/schools/{schoolId}/chats/{discussionId}/messages`

**User Claim code from Cloud Function**

Looking at the cloud function logs, we have verified that the userClaim is being set.

```js
return firebaseAdmin
    .auth()
    .setCustomUserClaims(
        uid, {
            chatFlatList: 'id1 id2 id3'
        }
    );
```

**UPDATE #1**

Tried the following variation where rules skip/omit the check on userClaim and auth.token.

However, still same permission error.

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if false;
        }

        match /schools/{schoolId}/chats/{discussionId}/messages {
          allow write: if false;
          allow read: if request.auth != null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply allowing all access to messages, just to see if the problem is specifically with the interpretation of chatFlatList?

Comment: @Doug, post is updated with listing for trying rules setup as you descibe.  I was wondering - is it maybe that the main *"global rule"* `match /{document=**}` , somehow overwrites the custom rule for messages?  I was trying to find something in the docs that explains if at least 1 rule is matched for **true**, then that is enough .. not sure if I missed that detail, but didn't see it. Thanks

Comment: You can reject the entire database like that, then allow specific parts.  It's totally doable.  You just can't allow some part of the database, then reject it later.  Once allowed, always allowed for that user.

Comment: Since firebase console asks for feedback - on this point I would just like to take the opportunity to say: Overall the different Firebase tiers have been straight fwd to ramp up on and work with. But - respectfully (big Firebase advocate here!) - security rules area has been the most cumbersome (not so intuitive) to navigate/manage. E.g. no real way to debug errors in the rules logic it seems. Simulator doesn't support debug logs to determine which rule is matching for true or false, nor allows userClaim cfgs. Either the rules cfg works or it doesn't :(. Any guidance, very apprect'd :). Thanks

Comment: I understand, these are issues that people at Firebase are thinking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution (seems to be working), which includes the check on `chatFlatList` *user claim variable* (from original question) for a substring :

```js
        match /schools/{schoolId}/chats/{discussionId}/messages {
          allow write: if false;
          allow read: if request.auth != null
          && request.auth.token.chatFlatList.matches(discussionId);
        }
```

Figured this out thanks to:

1. [Firebase storage rules based on custom parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476964/firebase-storage-rules-based-on-custom-parameters)

   - Here the post shows there **is not** any `$` notation to access the path var. I recall seeing this in a *security rules* example code example - *maybe  it's specific to database tiers?*
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/#string
3. https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html

   - Trying some example inputs here, to get an understanding for how to create the regex's.

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue here is that you are writing a rule on the collection called messages.

> All match statements should point to documents, not collections.
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure

You should try adding /{document=**} after your path to messages, something like:

```
    match /schools/{schoolId}/chats/{discussionId}/messages/{document=**} {
      allow write: if false;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me if I wanted to read and write all collection but not one collection named "backStage";

```
rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{collection}/{document} {
          allow read: if true
          allow write: if (collection != "backStage");
        }
      }
    }
```